# Return "self" for the return type of a function inside a PHP trait

Tags: php, traits, return-type, fluent

In a PHP trait, can I use `self` as the return type of a method? Will it reference the class that imports the trait?

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

trait MyTrait
{

    public function setSomething(array $data): self
                                             // ^ is this ok?
    {
        $this->update($data);
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is valid. Using a trait is pretty much equivalent to copy-pasting its content onto the using class. Note that `object` is wholly different from `self` though (unrelated to traits).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In fact this is the ONLY thing you can do (referring to the instance or class).

```
class TestClass {
    use TestTrait;
}

trait TestTrait {
    public function getSelf(): self {
        echo __CLASS__ . PHP_EOL;
        echo static::class . PHP_EOL;
        echo self::class . PHP_EOL;

        return $this;
    }
}

$test = new TestClass;
var_dump($test->getSelf());
```

Output

```
TestClass
TestClass
TestClass
object(TestClass)#1 (0) {
}
```

Working [example](https://3v4l.org/HI8hb).

Answer (score 1):

You can use it as shown in the accepted answer, but there's a caveat: The trait can't appear in more than one class in the hierarchy. If your TestClass above becomes abstract or is extended by a SubTestClass, SubTestClass cannot `use` that trait. Failure to adhere to this condition will cause the interpreter to regard both implementations of `setSomething` as unique methods. As you are already aware, method overloading is not welcome in PHP. So your `self` return type will fail.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `static` instead.

This way, your IDE will be able to access other properties of the used class rather than the trait only.

```php
trait MyTrait
{
    public function something(): static
    {
        // return something from the original class;
    }
}
```

I figured this out while working with Enums in PHP. I created a trait to help me keep track of the most useful functions that can be used with [PHP's Enumerations](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.enumerations.php).

Take the example below:

```php
trait EnumTrait
{
    /**
     * Get a random enum value.
     *
     * @return self
     */
    public static function random(): self
    {
        $enums = self::cases();

        return $enums[array_rand($enums)];
    }
}
```

When I use this trait in my enum class, e.g.; `App\Enums\Status` and I call `Status::random()`, the enum object is returned no doubt, but my IDE loses sight of the other properties within the Enum class and only sees the trait's properties. However, when you change the return type of the function to `static`, IDE now sees the original `Status` enum class and its original properties.

✅ Solution

```php
trait EnumTrait
{
    /**
     * Get a random enum value.
     *
     * @return static
     */
    public static function random(): static
    {
        $enums = self::cases();

        return $enums[array_rand($enums)];
    }
}
```

PS, I use VSCode.